# Emacs setting key binding for multi-occur-in-matching-buffers with default argument

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I want to set a key binding for the following function: `'multi-occur-in-matching-buffers`. This what I added to my `.emacs`:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-p") 'multi-occur-in-matching-buffers)
```

This works fine but I would like to have the default behaviour to look up in all the buffers. This is done by passing `.` as a default argument.
How do I change the line in my config so it does that?

Gracias!

Comment: This question is not a duplicate as it is not asking how to search.  It is asking how to pass arguments to a function which is being mapped.  I believe the answer can be found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3434098/155299), but the questions are fundamentally different.

Comment: I don't want it to be interactive. And my question is not necessarily about searching buffers but how to define a key-binding with a default argument.

Comment: It would have to be interactive though.  If the function is non-interactive then it wouldn't be able to be bound to a key.  Create an interactive wrapper function that sets the default values you want and passing the remainder to the original function.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate partly because the *intent* of the question is identical (a key binding to search all buffers for a given regexp), and partly because one of the answers to that question is *exactly* what was being asked for. If the question was a generic "how to define a key-binding which passes a default argument to some arbitrary function" it would not have been a duplicate of this (although IIRC there are duplicates for that question too), but this question was actually very specific.